# Slice cv::Mat() Like Python Numpy

Tags: python, c++, slice

In Python, we can slice a n-dim numpy array easily, like

```py
import numpy as np

arr = np.random.rand(1, 480, 640, 2)
x = arr[0, :, :, 0]
y = arr[0, :, :, 1]
```

Is there a convenient C++ method to slice an OpenCV `cv::Mat` like in Python?